# hyperlink control vs link button vs ImageButton vs button control in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

What is difference between hyperlink control , link button , ImageButton , button control in ASP.NET. Which one to use when?

Let say I have requirement to show an image. On click of the image I need to do something. It can be done using above controls. Which one is better to use?

Answer (score 5):

`HyperLink` is used to navigate, it renders to an anchor tag

`LinkButton` renders also to an anchor tag but with postback to server behavior. It's used to have a button with link look & feel.

`ImageButton` renders to an input control of type image and can be user to post to server or perform some client side action.

If you need to use that control to implement navigation, use `HyperLink`, otherwise you could use `ImageButton`